# Running jest tests in parallel based on a list of parameters

Tags: javascript, concurrency, parallel-processing, jestjs

In my case I have a test file containing a few hundred tests using jest

```
describe('my test-suite', () => {
   test('test 1', () => {
       expect(1).toBe(1);
   });
   //another hundred tests...
});
```

What I need to do now is to run these tests for different parameters, specified on a config file. More in details in my case the config file specifies some external parameters for external services (think like DB access parameters) and ideally I would like to keep exactly the same structure I already have, running the same tests multiple times against all these external services.

Ideally I should be able to do something like:

```
const paramList = [{
    name: 'service 1'
}, {
    name: 'service 2'
}];

describe('my parallel test-suite', () => {
    it.each(paramList)("testing against $name", ({name}) => {

        //just what I had before
        describe('my test-suite', () => {
           test('test 1', () => {
               expect(1).toBe(1);
           });
           //another hundred tests...
        });

    });
});
```

Ideally the next step would be to replace the `test.each` with `test.concurrent.each` and being able to run my tests in parallel against all the different external services.

Unfortunately with the code (and Jest version 27.4.7) above what I get is:

```
Cannot nest a describe inside a test. Describe block "my test-suite" cannot run because it is nested within "service service 1".

Tests cannot be nested. Test "test 1" cannot run because it is nested within "service service 1".
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a describe block in an `each` loop. Run each test in its own loop and then it will work. Something like this:

```
describe('my parallel test-suite', () => {
    it.each(paramList)("testing against $name", ({name}) => {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
    it.each(paramList)("another test against $name", ({name}) => {
        expect(2).toBe(2);
    });
    //another hundred tests...
});
```